# How to transform $- \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1 - x e^{-x}) \ \mathrm{d}x$ into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n^{n+2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761047/calculate-int-0-infty-leftx-log-leftex-x-right-right-dx), I was helped to determine the value of an improper integral. Now, I would like to understand how to get this result, and my calculus is a bit rusty.

I would like to understand these steps:
$$
\begin{align}
- \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1 - x e^{-x}) \ \mathrm{d}x &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \,  \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} \, e^{-n x} \ \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n^{n+2}}.
\end{align}
$$

I think I recognize Taylor series, but I'm not able to reproduce these steps myself.

Comment: Some minor steps (namely the interchanging of the integral with the infinite series and a u-substitution) are omitted, but the basic outline of the steps are 1) Maclaurin expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ and 2) applying the Gamma function.

Answer (score 2):

You have the reduction formula
$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^k e^{-nx} \, dx = \left[ -\frac{1}{n} x^k e^{-nx} \right]_0^{\infty} + \frac{k}{n} \int_0^{\infty} x^{k-1} e^{-nx} \, dx = \frac{k}{n} \int_0^{\infty} x^{k-1} e^{-nx}. $$
Together with the formula $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-nx} \, dx$, this gives
$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-nx} \, dx = \frac{n!}{n^{n+1}}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\frac1{1-u} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u^n$$

and the convergence is uniform on $[0,\delta]$ for any $0 < \delta < 1$, we can integrate both sides and the series term by term to get

$$\ln(1-u) = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{n}$$

Then use the fact $\int_0^{\infty} x^m e^{-x}dx = m!$

Comment: It seems to me that $\ln(1-u) = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n}$ (note the minus).

Comment: Oh yes. Fixed. Thanks. @M.Misouri